# How to get Script Parameters ( SuiteScript 2.0) using VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I would like to know if there is any way to get all the scripts parameters when you create a new script (SuiteScript 2.0) using **VS Code**.

I'm aware that it is possible when using Eclipse IDE but I do really would like to keep using VS Code as I'm already using for Python and JavaScript.

This is what I'm looking for:

```
/**
 * Function definition to be triggered before record is loaded.
 * 
 * Task #5060 : calculate PO Spent Amount and Balance in realtime
 *
 * @param {Object} scriptContext
 * @param {Record} scriptContext.newRecord - New record
 * @param {Record} scriptContext.oldRecord - Old record
 * @param {string} scriptContext.type - Trigger type
 * @Since 2015.2
 */
```

BTW, I'm already using VS Code Intelisense and NetSuite Uploader extensions.

Thanks

Comment: Is this for custom code, or for the Netsuite inbuilt modules ?

Comment: Custom codes that uses NetSuite modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, there are no official plugins from Netsuite for VS Code, only Eclipse & Webstorm are available. However, there is an unofficial plugin from [Head-in-the-Cloud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9wrP5GrFTU) that might do what you're after.