# SuiteScript with Intellisense in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have the **latest Visual Studio Code**.
I have installed the **latest SuiteCloud Extension for VS Code**.

There is no intellisense.

I have also installed the SuiteNippets extension -- which is ok--but not full intellisense.

I am baffled as to why this is missing. Do I need to import/reference something from NetSuite--despite using their extension already?

**How do I enable intellisense in VS Code for SuiteScript?**

Comment: Unfortunately at this point in time, [SuiteSnippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ericbirdsall.SuiteSnippets) is going to be your only option for SuiteScript intellisense in VS Code

Answer (score 0):

See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65472285/how-to-get-script-parameters-suitescript-2-0-using-vs-code) to a similar question. It's possible to use the [Head-in-the-Cloud bundle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q9wrP5GrFTU) to create javascript transpiled from TypeScript files. The code completion is good and you have the added benefit of type checking.

Comment: Does using it require me to install their bundle into NetSuite?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I don't know why, but they've got a custom script to manage the upload of the js file in to Netsuite.

Comment: Hmm. That's a deal-breaker for me.